# Filtering non-SQL DataGridView

Tags: datagridview, filtering

Hello StackOverFlow folks,

I have seen several ways to filter DataGridView with information retrieved from a SQL query.
However I am stuck in filtering a non-SQL DataGridView.

I actually have the following DataGridView:

Program | Project | Issues | Risks

I would like to display just the rows with issues higher than 0.

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks!!!

Comment: How is your datagridview populated? Is it databound or manually populated?

Comment: It is manually populated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I still couldn't find a way to solve in that way, however I found a reasonable workaround.

I am simply not adding the registers with issues = 0...

It might not be out of the box or best practice, but it worked fine for me.